# Arithmetic operators on lists/tuples in Python?

Tags: python, list, tuples, arithmetic-expressions

I have a couple functions like this:

```
object obj.getChild(childIndex)
int obj.numChildren()
```

So I am using these to create this function:

```
collection obj.getChildren()
```

I am flexible in the return type, but I will doing a lot of "subtraction", "multiplication" using another list. So something like this:

```
children = obj.getChildren()
children = [5,10,15,20,25]

globalChildren = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,14,16,18,20]

difference = children - globalChildren
difference = [15,25]

shared = children * globalChildren
shared = [5,10,20]
```

Is there a fast and elegant way to do these or do I have to go through each element one by one and gather the elements manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [`set`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set)s

```
children = {5,10,15,20,25}

globalChildren = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,14,16,18,20}

difference = children - globalChildren
shared = children & globalChildren
```

Comment: Thanks, can you please tell me what collection type are those `{}`?